# representation formula for the porous medium equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde

Consider the Cauchy problem for the nonlinear diffusion equation (or the porous medium equation):
\begin{equation}\nonumber%\label{eqn: LV 2-species scaled convolution type}
\textbf{(P)}
\begin{cases}
%\vspace{3mm} 
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(u^{\beta}\,\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right),\ \ &(x,t)\in\mathbb{R}\times(0,\infty),\\
%\vspace{3mm} 
u(x,0)=f(x)\ge0,\ \ &x\in\mathbb{R},%\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $u=u(x,t)$ and $\beta>0$ is a constant.

(1) It is well-known that when $\beta=0$, $\textbf{(P)}$ becomes the Cauchy problem for the heat equation, and it allows an representation integral formula:
\begin{equation}
u(x,t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\,\pi\,t}}e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4\,t}}\,f(y)\,dy.
\end{equation}
See for instance, [http://www.math.ualberta.ca/~xinweiyu/527.1.08f/lec12.pdf](http://www.math.ualberta.ca/%7Exinweiyu/527.1.08f/lec12.pdf). However, when $\beta\neq0$, does $\textbf{(P)}$ admit an representation formula?

(2) Suppose that $u=u(x,t)$ solves $\textbf{(P)}$. Can we show that the following integral
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
\bigg|
u^{\beta+1}\,\left(\frac{u_{xx}}{u}\right)^5 \left(\frac{u_{xxx}}{u}\right)^2\left(\frac{u_{x}}{u}\right)^3
\bigg|
\,dx<\infty?
\end{equation}
Any reference, suggestion, idea, or comment is welcome. Thank you!